# Run local PHP script from ASP.NET code

Tags: php, asp.net, .net

I need to run a specific PHP script which is located in the same folder with ASP.NET application.

Surely I can run it via WebClient, for example, using full public URL of the website, but I thought maybe there's a more logical way? To somehow launch it locally?

Comment: Using apache thrift, you can develop services that work between PHP and asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run the php file locally but if it does not rely on user interaction or external browser assets by using:

```
Process.Start("/path/to/php path/to/the/file.php", "any additional parameters");
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/path/to/php path/to/the/file.php", "any additional parameters");
```

or just:

```
system("/path/to/php path/to/the/file.php");
```

You can refer to http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php